# Android - Accessing provider tag in manifest and change it's attribute value

Tags: java, android, manifest

In my Android app, the AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this.

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/camera_authorities"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

             <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

        </provider>
```

In my case I want to **change the authorities value in the provider tag in manifest programmatically** from activity class. I have found the way to change metadata value using Bundle and PackageManager but i have no idea on this one. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the authorities value in the provider tag in manifest programmatically from activity class

Sorry, that is not possible.